# Dropdown binding from database in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind to values to fields on Edit button. Previously all were working fine but suddenly dropdown(Gender) control is not binding. Here is code-
HTML UI-

```
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            Gender :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control input-sm"  data-ng-model="newemployee.Gender" required>
                                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select</option>
                                <option value='1'>Male</option>
                                <option value='0'>Female</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Here is controller to bind values to controls-

```
$scope.EditEmployee = function (EID) {
        for (i in $scope.employees) {
            if ($scope.employees[i].EmpId == EID) {
                $scope.newemployee = {
                    EmpId: $scope.employees[i].EmpId,
                    Name: $scope.employees[i].Name,
                    Age: $scope.employees[i].Age,
                    Gender: $scope.employees[i].Gender,
                    City: $scope.employees[i].City
                };
            }
        }
    };
```

Text fields values are getting bind but dropdown showing blank

Comment: Please create plnkr/fiddle.

Comment: Are you sure that the value of `$scope.employees[i].Gender` is "", "1" or "2"? If you have anything else, then you will see a blank option in the dropdown. Also, like @hva.narola said it would be better if you could provide a plunker/fiddle.

Comment: yaa , I am sure that $scope.employees[i].Gender is 1(for Male) or 0(for Female). By the way I already said that it was working fine till date but suddenly not working

Comment: Can any one tell me that how to provide code using plunker/fiddle. because I have not used it yet

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
data-ng-model="newemployee.Gender"
```

to

```
ng-model="newemployee.Gender"
```

Reference : [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Regards

Comment: I changed to ng-model but still same result.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
in dropdown use -  ng-model="newemployee.Gender"

in option use   -   <option ng-model="newemployee.Gender">Male</option>
                    <option ng-model="newemployee.Gender">Female</option>
```

Comment: ok, I had face same issue but I got solution with help of this so I think i suggest you try this too..

Comment: <select id="ddlstatus" class="form-control" ng-model="newemployee";" ng-options="newemployee.Gender for s in newemployee track by snewemployee.id">
                                 <option data-ng-repeat="x in newemployee" value="{{x.id}}">{{x.Gender}}</option>
                            </select>

Comment: Okay,it seems good but I had issue that I am saving gender in DB in either 1 or 0 in so when I select any employee to edit,the dropdown fills with either 1 or 0 accordingly

Comment: try to use this.....<option ng-model="newemployee.Gender.value" value="1">Male</option> ...... Its work with my application